# ¿Cómo pasar el valor de input a un modal?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Estoy intentando mostrar en un `modal` el valor de un `input` ingresado en una tabla HTML por medio de jQuery, estoy trayendo estos valores en el `modal` pero no me trae el valor del `input`. ¿Cómo podría mostrarlo?.

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.boton').click(function () {
                $('#modal1').toggleClass('hidden');
                var valores = "";                   

                $(this).parents("tr").find("td").each(function () {
                    valores += '<p>' + $(this).html() + "</p>";
                    console.log(valores); 
                });

                $('.modal-content').append(valores);
            });
            $('#botonCerrar').click(function () {
                $('#modal1').toggleClass('hidden');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías obtener el valor del input guardarlo en una variable y después de copiar el contenido en el modal agregar el valor al input que esta en el modal, algo así:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".boton").click(function() {
      $("#modal1").toggleClass("hidden");
      var valores = "";
      var valorInput = $(this).parents('tr').find('input[type="text"]').val();

      $(this)
        .parents("tr")
        .find("td")
        .each(function() {
          valores += "<p>" + $(this).html() + "</p>";
        });

      $(".modal-content").append(valores);
      $(".modal-content").find('input[type="text"]').val(valorInput);
    });

    $("#botonCerrar").click(function() {
      $("#modal1").toggleClass("hidden");
    });
  });
```

Comment: Perfecto funciona a la perfección gracias.

Comment: Si la respuesta de @Dilver fue la correcta deberías de marcarlo para que otros al encontrarse con tu problema sepan cual fue la respuesta que te ayudo.
Saludos